# PyPdf: split each page in two, pad with blank space

Tags: pdf, pypdf

I have a PDF file (A4, portrait layout), each page of which I want to split in a half of height. The output document should also be A4 and portrait layout, but lower half of each page needs to be blank.

I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/15743413/822789 but did not understand how to add blank space with mediaBox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really know PyPDF2 all that well, but I am the author of [pdfrw](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/tree/master) and if I understand your question, pdfrw can certainly do what you want quite easily.  I need to document it a bit better, but I had a preexisting
[unspread.py](https://github.com/pmaupin/pdfrw/tree/master/examples/unspread.py) example that splits pages left and right, to chop down tabloid pages into the original pages.  Here is a modified version of that example.  This version will split pages top and bottom, and also change the size of the output page so that it matches the input page:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
usage:   splitv.py my.pdf

Creates splitv.my.pdf

This is similar to unspread.py, in that it creates
a new file that has twice the pages of the old file.

It is different in two ways:

1) It splits pages top and bottom rather than left and right
2) The destination pages are the same size as the source pages,
   and the output is placed at the top.
'''

import sys
import os

from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageMerge


def splitpage(src):
    ''' Split a page into two (top and bottom)
    '''
    # Yield a result for each half of the page
    for y_pos in (0, 0.5):

        # Create a blank, unsized destination page.
        page = PageMerge()

        # add a portion of the source page to it as
        # a Form XObject.
        page.add(src, viewrect=(0, y_pos, 1, 0.5))

        # By default, the object we created will be
        # at coordinates (0, 0), which is the lower
        # left corner.  To move it up on the page
        # to the top, we simply use its height
        # (which is half the source page height) as
        # its y value.
        page[0].y = page[0].h

        # When we render the page, the media box will
        # encompass (0, 0) and all the objects we have
        # placed on the page, which means the output
        # page will be the same size as the input page.
        yield page.render()


inpfn, = sys.argv[1:]
outfn = 'splitv.' + os.path.basename(inpfn)
writer = PdfWriter()
for page in PdfReader(inpfn).pages:
    writer.addpages(splitpage(page))
writer.write(outfn)
```

Comment: Great library @PatrickMaupin, thanks for making it available! Here I used it to cut a page in two halfs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13345593/split-each-pdf-page-in-two/62137420#62137420